# Mysql errno 150 cannot create buddies

Tags: mysql

I tired checking the relationship of the two tables, and matched everything up to see if they were using different engines. But for some reason I cannot create the "buddies" table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `buddies`;
CREATE TABLE `buddies` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `characterid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `buddyid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `pending` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `groupname` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ETC',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `buddies_ibfk_1` (`characterid`),
    CONSTRAINT `buddies_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`characterid`) REFERENCES `characters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7998 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `characters`;
CREATE TABLE `characters` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `accountid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `world` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `level` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `exp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `str` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `dex` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `luk` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `int` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `hp` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `mp` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `maxhp` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `maxmp` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `meso` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `hpApUsed` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `job` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `skincolor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fame` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `hair` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `face` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `faceMarking` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ap` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `map` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `spawnpoint` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `gm` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `party` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `buddyCapacity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '25',
    `createdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `guildid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `guildrank` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
    `allianceRank` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
    `guildContribution` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pets` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1,-1,-1',
    `sp` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0',
    `subcategory` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `rankMove` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `jobRank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `jobRankMove` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `marriageId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `familyid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `seniorid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `junior1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `junior2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `currentrep` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `totalrep` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `gachexp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fatigue` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `charm` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `craft` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `charisma` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `will` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sense` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `insight` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `totalWins` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `totalLosses` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pvpExp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pvpPoints` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rebirths` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `prefix` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `reborns` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `apstorage` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `elf` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `honourExp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `honourLevel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `accountid` (`accountid`),
    KEY `guildid` (`guildid`),
    KEY `familyid` (`familyid`),
    KEY `marriageId` (`marriageId`),
    KEY `seniorid` (`seniorid`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=124 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Well every time I execute above, I get:Error Code: 1005. Can't create table (errno: 150)    0.000 sec

Comment: An error message or two might be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `buddies` last so it can reference `characters`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b359c

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the order of the create tables? Buddies is trying to create a table with a foreign key constraint off of characters which may not exist yet.